# possible to use Passbook for gift cards

Tags: ios, wallet

I have a small business and was wondering if it's possible to use Passbook for gift cards? For example, someone buys a $50 gift certificate on our website and that gets delivered automatically to the other user.

Is there a major retailer that does this? I see passbook mostly for tickets (and to be honest, it's a bit unwieldy).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes - this is a valid use of Passbook now called Wallet on iOS 9.

- https://developer.apple.com/wallet/

Apple has ample sample code, working server implementations, automation and testing tools as well as several guides to let you know what is possible without digging into the code.

Most developers that do any sort of work with Passbook could quote you their assistance in running your campaign if you didn't want to DIY.

One major retailer that has had stored value in Passbook for more than a year now (2013) is Apple - both their retail gift cards and iTunes store/Mac App/iOS App/iBooks store combined balances. You can watch a video explaining how Apple rolled this out:

- https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2013-303/

I also believe that several companies are rolling out discounts/loyalty cards in addition to stored value - but that's a bit newer and I'm not sure that API is finished on Apple's end quite yet. You could easily accomplish that on your end with a web server and some custom coding to track your user through an iOS app or purely through the wallet and/or iBeacons to have the item check in with the server when presented at a POS terminal or other location in store.

Comment: thx - do you know any larger retailers that are doing something like this (other than apple who obviously has the upper had in all of this)? And yes, the iBeacon / loyalty card is really interesting too. Most of the examples I have seen have been WAY TOO CONFUSING - while that's part of the the point of gift cards (people not redeeming them), it seems like Passbook could be well-suited for this.

Comment: I avoided making a laundry list of people that are testing this. It becomes out dated rapidly and we're more about solving practical questions as opposed to making wiki lists. Hit me up in [chat] if you need more info...

Comment: not looking for a laundry list, would love one great example if you had it. Will dig around some on my own. thx for help

Comment: You have the one great example. Apple itself - I've also linked to the actual documentation - it doesn't matter what other have or will do if you can see what you can do today with the tools :-)

Comment: haha, other than Apple like a big-box like Gap / Target etc.... or online like Zynga etc...